# Removal of Diacritics using regex in JAVA

Tags: regex, diacritics

I know there has been questions similiar on SO but I am not sure if it fits my query

I am trying to replace all the diacritics like á, í, ó, ú, ý into a, i, o, u, y. Is there a consolidated   regex that would return only the diacritics so that I can replace them accordingly? 
kindly give me a detailed methodology of approaching this issue.

Comment: Considered using Normalizer?

Comment: That is the thing. We are not allowed to use Normalizer

Comment: The only thing available to do this without Normalizer is collation feature, which is available on a handful of languages. BRE and ERE supports this, and I think Perl should have support for this. Otherwise, if you don't have a Normalizer, you won't be able to write clean code to remove the diacritic if it is a single character.